# Wrong encoding / chars in email via lettre

Tags: rust, character-encoding, html-email

I'm sending email from a rust program.

Email text is in a Postgresql database with encoding UTF8. I query database via postgres crate: https://crates.io/crates/postgres

I'm working on Windows. If I print the message seems correct:

[image]

But when I receive it on Thunderbird it display: "Questo =C3=A8 il"

If I read it from Gmail web interface it seems correct, but when I check "Show original message", it is wrong again.

I read messages with a query like this:

```
let query = "SELECT * FROM myschema.retrieve_messages($1, $2, $3, $4);";
for row in &db_client.query(query, &[&pg_working_date, &max_messages_per_run, &_force_retry, &run_id]).unwrap()
```

Then I loop on results, and put them in a Vec. I retrieve body with:

```
mail_body: row.get("mail_body")
```

If I print body of message with:

```
println!("Body is: {}", m.mail_body);
```

It seems ok.

Then I use lettre crate to send email https://crates.io/crates/lettre

I connect like this:

```
    let mailer = SmtpTransport::relay(&smtp_server)
    .unwrap()
    .credentials(smpt_credentials)
    .build();
```

And I ship message with this code:

```
        let shipping_message = Message::builder()
        .from("Hello <shippingaddress@shippngdomain.something>".parse().unwrap())
        .to(m.email_address.parse().unwrap())
        .subject(m.mail_subject)
        .body(m.mail_body)
        .unwrap();
```

And then the shipment:

```
match mailer.send(&shipping_message) {some other irrelevant code}
```

There is something wrong in code? What can I check?

Comment: *"... but when I check "Show original message", it is wrong again."* - it's not wrong. It is encoded as quoted-printable. That's what need to be done for compatibility reasons. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding

Comment: Or better: it is a second (stacked) encoding. One gives you the characters, but emails likes to be pure 7-bit, so there will be a second transformation, from single UTF-8 bytes to quoted-printable (and standard). Probably some mail clients just try to decode (also if you miss to describe the encoding). Thunderbird may be more strict (I see correct characters on normal mails, so I assume you forget to specify the encoding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call [`MessageBuilder::body`](https://docs.rs/lettre/latest/lettre/message/struct.MessageBuilder.html#method.body) your body is encoded:

> Automatically gets encoded with `7bit`, `quoted-printable` or `base64` `Content-Transfer-Encoding`, based on the most efficient and valid encoding for body.

If this behaviour is not desirable, you can use a [`MIME`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) body with [`SinglePart`](https://docs.rs/lettre/latest/lettre/message/struct.SinglePart.html) instead.

I think this should do the trick for you:

```
        let shipping_message = Message::builder()
        .from("Hello <shippingaddress@shippngdomain.something>".parse().unwrap())
        .to(m.email_address.parse().unwrap())
        .subject(m.mail_subject)
        .singlepart(SinglePart::plain(m.mail_body)) // plain UTF-8 encoding
        .unwrap();
```